# Cannot find Japanese kanji in Chinese dictionary

Tags: character-identification, characters

I do not have any historical dictionaries installed (yet) in Pleco. I am trying to look up a character I found in the handle of a contributor on the Japanese SE, but could not find it in Pleco.

Don't all Japanese kanji have Chinese (繁体) equivalents? I have attached screenshots of the characters (closest character is 侵, but this one has a small 人 on the left rather than a small 刀):

[image: drawn character]

[image: picture of username handle]

Comment: [帰](http://www.zdic.net/z/19/js/5E30.htm)

Comment: How did you search for it and find it obj the sure. Can you tell mgs what buttons to press and where and what I should type? I am aware of how to use radicals to look up things I've a dictionary. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

it's 帰 (u+5e30), located in "[cjk unified ideographs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CJK_Unified_Ideographs)". it's a kanji, a character mainly used by japanese. the equivalent one in chinese is 歸 (u+6b78).

imo, the dictionary used is, well, not good enough. it maybe suitable for beginner, or amateur. any decent one would give you the answer directly:

[http://chardb.iis.sinica.edu.tw/search.jsp?q=帰&x=0&y=0&stype=0](http://chardb.iis.sinica.edu.tw/search.jsp?q=%E5%B8%B0&x=0&y=0&stype=0)

http://dict2.variants.moe.edu.tw/variants/rbt/word_attribute.rbt?quote_code=QTAyMDc1LTAwNQ

http://www.cns11643.gov.tw/AIDB/query_general_view.do?page=3&code=3067

lastly, i guessed the id "劫回帰" is derived from the manga "[Yu-Gi-Oh!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yu-Gi-Oh!)", have fun :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Could you please help me and tell me how to input a CJKV char using a Unicode value (such as u+6b78) on Android? Thanks.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Anyways, why do so many Chinese websites have numbers instead of letters. Maybe in China people are mute comfortable remembering numbers rather than pure DNS names. Any ideas?

Comment: sorry, i don't have a smartphone yet :(  however, i would suggest an app with hex code input, something like that one [ try with your own risk :) ]: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=uk.co.cwd.unicodekeyboard

Comment: about websites have numbers instead of letters. well, maybe ask new question for it, let people air their views about this one :)